# Search redirect and display to current page and thereafter direct to another when item is chosen

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am creating a vehicle hiring website. I display all the available vehicles and remove them from display once one is hired/booked out.

On my display page for my available vehicles I would like to have a search category using drop-down lists, However, I would like to carry out the search and return the user back to this page with the refined searched vehicles only. Thereafter once the user selects the vehicle he wants to book, he must then be directed to the next page.

My Vehicles ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Vehicles()
    {
        var e = db.Vehicles.Where(x => x.availability == true).ToList();
        return View(e);
    }
```

My Vehicles ActionResult, Post:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Vehicles(string locationUp, string vehicleID)
    {
        Session["V_LOC"] = locationUp;
        Session["V_ID"] = vehicleID;

        return RedirectToAction("Vehicle_Step_1", "Home");
    }
```

This, as it stands, directs the user to the second's step in booking a vehicle, How can I accommodate for the search to keep the user on the same page and refine the search and once the user chooses a vehicle then direct them to the second step?

I haven't done this before so I am a bit confused as to how to go ahead with this

Answer (score 0):

You can define a model, which defines user filters:

```
public class Filter 
{
    public string MaxPrice { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
}
```

From your search page, you need to post this filter to the controller to refine the search, so add another action method that user can post to:

```
[HttpPost] // <-- note that this one is HttpPost
public ActionResult Vehicles(Filter userFilter)
{
    // refine the search and send the user back to Vehicles view
    var e = db.Vehicles.Where(x => x.availability == true && 
                              x.Price <= userFilter.MaxPrice &&
                              string.Equal(x.Model, userFilter.Make).ToList();
    return View(e);
}
```

This is your easiest option... the alternative would be to do your search using Ajax and update the search result on the same page using Ajax and JavaScript (which would be more complex for sure).